# incrementing notification.number in android

Tags: android, notifications

I am using notifications in my Android application. Whenever i receive a notification, i am trying to increment the number of unread notifications using notification.number as in the code below.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
"A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.number += 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);

PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is the title",
"This is the text", activity);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

But, no matter how many notifications i receive, the counter is not incrementing. Its always displaying 1 only. I am not getting what is wrong here. Could anybody help me...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are creating a new notification object. just create once,  check if it exists in field

```
public class main extends Activity {

Notification notification=null;


//....
if (this.notification == null)
    this.notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

this.notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
this.notification.number += 1;
```

Comment: Okay, in your code, where should i declare the notification variable ?

Comment: in your main class (Activity)

Comment: In my application, i have used the code for notifications in Broadcast Receiver class which receives notification broadcasts. As you said, i tried making notification variable a class member(its now a local member of some function). But it still did not work.

Comment: try making it static, static Notification notification=null;
in your Receiver class

Comment: yeah i tried that too, in this case, even after all the unread notifications are viewed, the count remains the same. I mean its not reset to 0.

Comment: Thats different case, then you need save the counter in other storage, like Shared Preferences. or set notification.number to 0 in NotificationReceiver.class when user view the notification ( onResume or onCreate)

Comment: Is there a way to know when the user views all the unread notifications ?

Comment: I'm not sure how your application works. but you can decrement notification number, only if intent contains boolean key. Add it using putBoolean() after Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);

Comment: I am not creating an intent for the receiver class at all. I have registered it as a receiver in the manifest. Anyway, thanks for your response. If i get it somehow, i will post the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: But the code you gave works i think. It just didnt work in my case. Mine is a different scenario.